# How do I prevent corrupted record in Kaggle TFRecord file?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, kaggle, tfrecord

I'm attempting to write tiled images to kaggle/working/..., but when I try to re-read the first record to confirm that the write worked, I added the code

```
    # Read back one record to confirm:
    raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset( output_path )
    print( "raw_dataset", raw_dataset, file = sys.stderr )

    for raw_record in raw_dataset.take(1):
        example = tf.train.Example()
        example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
        print("Reading back raw_record from", output_path, example)
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
---> 70         for raw_record in raw_dataset.take(1):
     71             example = tf.train.Example()
     72             example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
     ...
DataLossError: corrupted record at 0
```

I have tried several variations, all give the same results. Help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  The program that was writing the TFRecords was specifying that the writer GZIP its output, but the reader didn't know that.  By making the following change in creating the reader

```
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset( output_path, compression_type = 'GZIP' )
```

I am now able to read the records.